# Show entire question in a popup on mouseover

Tags: feature-request, questions

On Google, when the user mouses over an item in the search list page, the entire page is shown in a popup to the right of the item:

[image: Google screenshot]

It would be useful if such a feature also existed for Stack Overflow questions, so when the user mouses over a question in the question list the entire question is displayed in a popup, making it easy to see all the question in full without going back and forth.

Comment: That's one of the most annoying features from Google.

Comment: If this feature is implemented then Stack Exchange sites can provide an option to enable/disable the google-like popup.

Comment: @AzizShaikh Stack Exchange sites aren't big on preferences

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I dont disagree with you but there are some preferences that the sites remember for each user, such as 'enable/disable random ordering' on review page, last tab used, custom sort order, page size, etc.

Comment: doesn't that help in reading the whole question?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. Where does it end, should *every* link you mouse-over give you a full-page tooltip, so you don't have to go "back and forth"?

This is solved at the browser-UI level, not on a site-by-site basis. The solution for you is to learn to use tabbed browsing. Figure out how to ctrl-click or middle-click links and navigate tabs. Learn to actually use the facilities already provided by your browser and your experience will be improved across the *entire* Internet, not just on those sites that implement this horrid full-page-tool-tip idea.